# ERROR: config_template is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler

Tags: openstack, ansible

I am trying to install Openstack through Ansible for a single node using All IN ONE.

When I run `setup-everything.yml` file, I am receiving following error:

> ERROR: config_template is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler

Can you please help on the issue?

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing the playbook. But it seems that there is wrong indentation of config_template parameter in the playbook.

Comment: I did not mention any config_template params manually at anywhere, as Ansible itself having playbooks for Openstack.

Comment: Paste part of your playbook with a problem. Run with -vvvv to get more info.

Comment: It doesn't give any other detailed error. What I am missing ? Which file you need to look further?, I can share it with you. 
`ubuntu:/opt/openstack-ansible/playbooks$ ansible-playbook setup-everything.yml -vvvv
ERROR: config_template is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler
ubuntu: /opt/openstack-ansible/playbooks$ ansible-playbook -vvvv setup-everything.yml
ERROR: config_template is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler`

Comment: There should be a line in the error message: `The error appears to have been in...` where line of problem code is indicated

Comment: When people ask you to add information to your question, do it by *editing the question* rather than by leaving comments.  Putting the information in the question makes it easier to find and easier to format (which makes it easier to read, which makes it more likely people will try to help out).

Answer (score 1):

I know that this answer is a little late but I found this and thought to try and help others out should they run into this.

It's very likely that the system was not bootstrapped. We see this error from time to time when the action plugin is not present on the system. With OpenStack-Ansible you will need to retrieve the roles and plugins from the `ansible-role-requirements.txt` file. After you've cloned the software the first step in deployment is usually running `./scripts/bootstrap-ansible.sh` which would install Ansible into a venv, retrieve your roles, libraries, & plugins, and then create the `openstack-ansible` CLI wrapper. You can also simply use the `ansible-galaxy` command with the `ansible-role-requirements.txt` if you don't want to run that script. After you have the roles and libs you will likely no longer see that error. More documentation on getting started can be found here: https://docs.openstack.org/developer/openstack-ansible/developer-docs/quickstart-aio.html

You can get access to the config_template module source code here: https://github.com/openstack/openstack-ansible-plugins/blob/master/action/_v2_config_template.py should you have issues specifically with the module or jump into the #openstack-ansible channel on freenode where there's generally someone available to help out.

Answer (score 0):

`config_template` is a custom module developed by the OpenStack team. If you get `ERROR: config_template is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler` it might mean that Ansible can not find the module could be an indention / syntax error as well. Check if the module `config_template` is in your `ANSIBLE_LIBRARY` environment variable. You can also pass the path via command line with `--module-path`

Also the [pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/12555) for this module was closed by the Ansible developers. So it is likely that you can find a similar functionality in a module supported by the Ansible developers.